# Kivy 2 (Python3) windows exe packing not work

Tags: python, windows, kivy

Also i use pip3.9 for install (i cant use python3 -m ...)
I check lib its is installed ok.

Wneh i start exe file nothing happen.
Looks like lot of problems with my build.

I can run it only :

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

If i try like this:

```
$ python3 -m pyinstaller main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller\__main__.py", line 80, in run
    import PyInstaller.building.makespec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyInstaller'
(kivy_venv)
```

What can be critical here, any suggestion.

I found warn logs file with :

```
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), subprocess (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.storage' - imported by engine.editor.layout (top-level), engine.editor.sceneGUICOntainer (top-level), engine.editor_main (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.properties' - imported by engine.editor.layout (top-level), engine.editor.sceneGUICOntainer (top-level), engine.config (top-level), engine.common.modifycation (top-level), engine.common.commons (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.logger' - imported by engine.common.commons (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.graphics' - imported by engine.editor.layout (top-level), engine.editor.sceneGUICOntainer (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.core' - imported by engine.editor_main (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.metrics' - imported by engine.editor_main (top-level), engine.common.commons (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.uix' - imported by G:\web_server\xampp\htdocs\PRIVATE_SERVER\PYTHON\cross-k\cross-k\main.py (top-level), components.main_form.layout (top-level), engine.editor_main (top-level), engine.editor.layout (top-level), engine.editor.sceneGUICOntainer (top-level), engine.common.modifycation (top-level), engine.common.commons (top-level), engine.common.operations (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.app' - imported by G:\web_server\xampp\htdocs\PRIVATE_SERVER\PYTHON\cross-k\cross-k\main.py (top-level), components.main_form.layout (top-level), engine.editor_main (top-level), engine.editor.layout (top-level), engine.editor.sceneGUICOntainer (top-level), engine.common.commons (top-level)
missing module named 'kivy.config' - imported by G:\web_server\xampp\htdocs\PRIVATE_SERVER\PYTHON\cross-k\cross-k\main.py (top-level), engine.editor_main (top-level)
missing module named kivy - imported by G:\web_server\xampp\htdocs\PRIVATE_SERVER\PYTHON\cross-k\cross-k\main.py (top-level), engine.editor_main (top-level)
```